# How to convert a list of items into variables in python?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of items in python something like this:
input:

```
a=['nt','mt','pt']
```

I want to make each item in the above list as a variable and then assign that variable to a regex involving that variable.

output:
I want something like this:

```
nt=re.compile("%s=[a-z]+&" %nt)
mt=re.compile("%s=[a-z]+&" %mt)
pt=re.compile("%s=[a-z]+&" %pt)
```

how do i go about doing this ???
Thanks.
[sorry didn't pose the question in the best way possible ]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) Don't use variables, use a dictionary:

```
d = {name: re.compile("%s=[a-z]+&" % name) for name in a}
```

Comment: If using Python 2.6 or earlier: `d = dict((name, re.compile("%s=[a-z]+&" % name) for name in a)`

Comment: then what if I later on want to use the above assigned regex on a string?

Comment: @abhinav: Simply retrieve it from the dictionary: `d["nt"]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unquestionably best to use dictionary keys, not variables. But FYI in Python variables are actually stored in a dictionary anyway, which you can access by calling `vars()` or `locals()`. That means it *is* possible to create variables dynamically just by assigning to this dictionary, e.g.:

```
>>> new_var_name = 'my_var'
>>> vars()[new_var_name] = "I'm your new variable!"
>>> print my_var
"I'm your new variable!"
```

To be honest I don't know how tampering with `vars()` could ever be justifiable. But it's interesting, at least. Anyway, use Sven Marnach's answer.

Comment: Changing the dictionary returned by `vars()` or `locals()` is not allowed.  You can only change the dictionary returned by `globals()`.  Your code only works because you executed it at global scope, it would not work inside a function.

Comment: True. This obviously isn't a tenable solution, just an interesting quirk.